# How to merge rows based on common columns in R

Tags: r, merge

I am working in a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
vims <- data.frame(
  patient_ID = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b"),
  Date = c(2020, 2020, 2018, 2020, 2028),
  Eye = c("Right", "Left", "Right", "Right", "Right"),
  V1 = c(21, 18, 30, 30, 18)
  V2 = c(28, 30, 15, 45, 60)
)
```

As you can see, the data has an ID and may have several evaluation on different dates for that same ID and further it may have different eye evaluations within the dates. I am trying to merge rows in order to be arrange by ID and date to obtain rows that contains the ID, the date and all the info for every eye in the same row (V1 for the right and left eye if available)

Comment: How should we interpret the difference between V1 and V2? You mention that V1 should be used for left and right eye, does that mean we can ignore V2?

Comment: I am sorry for my lack of information regarding the process and what I want to do. Khartik S answered, regardless I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

vims %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = c(patient_ID, Date), names_from = Eye, values_from = c(V1,V2))
# A tibble: 4 x 6
  patient_ID  Date V1_Right V1_Left V2_Right V2_Left
  <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1 a           2020       21      18       28      30
2 a           2018       30      NA       15      NA
3 b           2020       30      NA       45      NA
4 b           2028       18      NA       60      NA
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` alternative:

```
library(data.table)
vims <- as.data.table(vims)

dcast(vims, patient_ID+Date~Eye, value.var = c("V1","V2"))

   patient_ID Date V1_Left V1_Right V2_Left V2_Right
1:          a 2018      NA       30      NA       15
2:          a 2020      18       21      30       28
3:          b 2020      NA       30      NA       45
4:          b 2028      NA       18      NA       60
```